# Choosing one item from a symmetric set

Tags: tla+

I have a TLA+ spec akin to the following:

```
CONSTANT Items
VARIABLE item
```

And I'd like `Items` to be symmetric, and to select a single element from `Items` and store it into `item`.

I've been using `item = CHOOSE x \in Items: TRUE`, but I learned that this breaks symmetry on Items: TLC will always select the first item from the set.

I'd like to select a single item in a way that preserves symmetry, to allow TLC to explore all states.  I don't care *which* item we select -- only that it is one, and that it is from `Items`.  (Later, I need `item` to be `\in Items`.

While I'd prefer `item` to be a single element, it would also be okay for `item` to be a set of cardinality 1, so later I can check for `\subseteq Items`.

It was recommended to me to replace `CHOOSE` with `{x \in Items: TRUE}` to preserve symmetry and have the result be `\subseteq Items`, but this does not constrain the resulting set to cardinality 1.

Is there a way to ask TLA+ to give me a single item, or a set of cardinality 1, from a symmetric set of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned a bit more about TLA+/TLC since posting the question, and here's my answer:

To simply select an element from a symmetry set in the initial predicate:

```
item \in Items
```

or in an action:

```
item' \in Items
```

If you want to select an item that *matches a predicate*, as you can specify with CHOOSE, then this is the alternative:

```
item \in {x \in Items: P(x)}
```

This'll form a subset of Items that match the predicate, then select a single element of those.

Here's some data that shows the difference between this syntax and CHOOSE.  Consider this module:

```
----------------------------- MODULE ChooseDemo -----------------------------
CONSTANT Items
VARIABLE item

TypeInvariant == item \in Items

Init == item = CHOOSE x \in Items: TRUE

Next == item' \in {x \in Items: x /= item}
=============================================================================
```

When `Items` has three items:

- NOT a symmetry set: TLC finds 1 initial state and a total of 7 (3 distinct) states.
- symmetry set: TLC finds 1 initial state and a total of 3 (1 distinct) states.

Now consider this module:

```
--------------------------- MODULE SetFormingDemo ---------------------------
CONSTANT Items
VARIABLE item

TypeInvariant == item \in Items

Init == item \in {x \in Items: TRUE}

Next == item' \in {x \in Items: x /= item}
=============================================================================
```

When `Items` has three items:

- NOT a symmetry set: TLC finds 3 (3 distinct) initial states and a total of 9 (3 distinct) states.
- symmetry set: TLC finds 3 (1 distinct) initial state and a total of 5 (1 distinct) states.

Hence, by using the set-forming syntax, TLC finds more states than it did with CHOOSE.